GenProg for Haskell
I am linking to a similar question in which the person seemed to get it working. However, with the instructions I have followed nothing seems to work to get Haskell running.
System: Ubuntu 22.04
1) sudo apt install ghc
2) sudo apt install haskell-stack
3) sudo apt install cabal-install
4) stack new my-project
5) cd my-project
6) stack setup
7) stack build
8) stack exec my-project-exe
9) cabal init
10) cabal build
11) cabal run

I went into package.yaml and added genprog as a dependency:
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- genprog


Ran
1) stack build
2) import GenProg
3) cabal init
4) cabal ucabal install --only-dependencies
pdate
5) stack build

However, I get this error:
stack build
Writing implicit global project config file to: /home/jonny/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("Accept","application/json"),("User-Agent","The Haskell Stack")]
  path                 = "/haddock.stackage.org/snapshots.json"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (StatusCodeException (Response {responseStatus = Status {statusCode = 404, statusMessage = "Not Found"}, responseVersion = HTTP/1.1, responseHeaders = [("x-amz-request-id","S641EJDM5PG7K97D"),("x-amz-id-2","odmFBOYokfiL4Yv8ot2xUw4JWDdpEtjSQx8JzCZFgvbIzbZiH8kl4rJAUI3N7mOuTxIA9XqbcYk="),("Content-Type","application/xml"),("Transfer-Encoding","chunked"),("Date","Tue, 06 Aug 2024 04:15:23 GMT"),("Server","AmazonS3")], responseBody = (), responseCookieJar = CJ {expose = []}, responseClose' = ResponseClose}) "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code><Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message><BucketName>haddock.stackage.org</BucketName><RequestId>S641EJDM5PG7K97D</RequestId><HostId>odmFBOYokfiL4Yv8ot2xUw4JWDdpEtjSQx8JzCZFgvbIzbZiH8kl4rJAUI3N7mOuTxIA9XqbcYk=</HostId></Error>")


Here is my project layout:
tree
.
├── app
│   └── Main.hs
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── CHANGELOG.md.save0
├── dist-newstyle
│   ├── build
│   │   └── x86_64-linux
│   │       └── ghc-8.8.4
│   │           └── genetic-programming-0.1.0.0
│   │               ├── build
│   │               │   ├── autogen
│   │               │   │   ├── cabal_macros.h
│   │               │   │   └── Paths_genetic_programming.hs
│   │               │   ├── Lib.dyn_hi
│   │               │   ├── Lib.dyn_o
│   │               │   ├── Lib.hi
│   │               │   ├── libHSgenetic-programming-0.1.0.0-inplace.a
│   │               │   ├── libHSgenetic-programming-0.1.0.0-inplace-ghc8.8.4.so
│   │               │   └── Lib.o
│   │               ├── cache
│   │               │   ├── build
│   │               │   └── config
│   │               ├── package.conf.inplace
│   │               │   ├── package.cache
│   │               │   └── package.cache.lock
│   │               ├── setup-config
│   │               └── x
│   │                   └── genetic-programming
│   │                       ├── build
│   │                       │   └── genetic-programming
│   │                       │       ├── autogen
│   │                       │       │   ├── cabal_macros.h
│   │                       │       │   └── Paths_genetic_programming.hs
│   │                       │       ├── genetic-programming
│   │                       │       └── genetic-programming-tmp
│   │                       │           ├── Main.hi
│   │                       │           └── Main.o
│   │                       ├── cache
│   │                       │   ├── build
│   │                       │   ├── config
│   │                       │   └── registration
│   │                       ├── package.conf.inplace
│   │                       │   ├── package.cache
│   │                       │   └── package.cache.lock
│   │                       └── setup-config
│   ├── cache
│   │   ├── compiler
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── elaborated-plan
│   │   ├── improved-plan
│   │   ├── plan.json
│   │   ├── solver-plan
│   │   ├── source-hashes
│   │   └── up-to-date
│   ├── packagedb
│   │   └── ghc-8.8.4
│   │       ├── genetic-programming-0.1.0.0-inplace.conf
│   │       ├── package.cache
│   │       └── package.cache.lock
│   ├── sdist
│   └── tmp
├── genetic-programming.cabal
├── genetic-programming.cabal.save0
├── LICENSE
├── package.yaml
├── README.md
├── Setup.hs
├── Setup.hs.save0
├── src
│   ├── GenProg.hs
│   └── Lib.hs
├── stack.yaml
├── stack.yaml.lock
└── test
    └── Spec.hs

25 directories, 50 files


Yet I get the error:
cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.8.4 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - genetic-programming-0.1.0.0 (lib) (configuration changed)
 - genetic-programming-0.1.0.0 (exe:genetic-programming) (configuration changed)
Configuring library for genetic-programming-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for genetic-programming-0.1.0.0..
Building library for genetic-programming-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling GenProg          ( src/GenProg.hs, /home/jonny/Documents/genetic-programming/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.4/genetic-programming-0.1.0.0/build/GenProg.o )

src/GenProg.hs:98:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Random’
    Perhaps you meant
      Control.Monad.Reader (needs flag -package-key mtl-2.2.2)
      Control.Monad.Cont (needs flag -package-key mtl-2.2.2)
      Control.Monad.Error (needs flag -package-key mtl-2.2.2)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
98 | import Control.Monad.Random
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

src/GenProg.hs:99:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘GenProg.GenExpr’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
99 | import GenProg.GenExpr
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Failed to build genetic-programming-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
exe:genetic-programming from genetic-programming-0.1.0.0).


and
cabal install MonadRandom
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Cannot build the executables in the package MonadRandom because it does
not contain any executables. Check the .cabal file for the package and make
sure that it properly declares the components that you expect.


❯ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
To revert to previous state run:
    cabal v2-update 'hackage.haskell.org,2024-08-06T14:23:10Z'
❯ cabal install MonadRandom
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Cannot build the executables in the package MonadRandom because it does
not contain any executables. Check the .cabal file for the package and make
sure that it properly declares the components that you expect.



I'm getting this same error on stack new myproject now. Perhaps some kind of outage.
